# svg are not seen on iphone

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have a problem with my code, I have an animation of an SVG, and it shows on all devices except iPhones.

I can't find solutions. here is the code of the SVG

```html
<div class="contenuto-svg">
  <svg viewBox="-85 -85 170 170" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <defs>
            <filter id="blur">
               <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="4.8" />
            </filter>
            <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="100%">
                <stop offset="10%" stop-color="#9DB6F2" />
                <stop offset="70%" stop-color="#FF5321" />
                <stop offset="20%" stop-color="#FF2E00" />
            </linearGradient>
        </defs>
        <path fill="url(#gradient)" style="opacity: 1;" filter="url(#blur)">
            <animate attributeName="d" dur="20000ms" repeatCount="indefinite"
                         values="M46.8,-53.3C55.6,-48.4,54.1,-28.9,52.8,-12.8C51.5,3.3,50.4,15.8,43.8,23.4C37.2,31,25.2,33.7,11.7,43.5C-1.7,53.2,-16.7,70.1,-28.8,69.8C-40.8,69.4,-49.9,51.7,-56.8,35.1C-63.7,18.4,-68.4,2.8,-67.8,-13.9C-67.2,-30.5,-61.2,-48.2,-49,-52.4C-36.8,-56.7,-18.4,-47.5,0.3,-47.9C19,-48.3,38,-58.1,46.8,-53.3Z;
 M38.9,-46.9C53,-34.5,69,-24.7,67.4,-14.7C65.8,-4.7,46.7,5.6,36.9,20C27,34.3,26.5,52.7,19.6,56.2C12.8,59.7,-0.3,48.3,-11.3,40.3C-22.3,32.3,-31.1,27.7,-34.4,20.5C-37.7,13.4,-35.5,3.8,-38.3,-11.3C-41.1,-26.5,-48.9,-47,-43.4,-61C-37.8,-75,-18.9,-82.3,-3.3,-78.4C12.4,-74.5,24.7,-59.3,38.9,-46.9Z;
                            
                                                    M25.6,-33.4C38.3,-19.9,57.2,-16.7,65.6,-6.1C74.1,4.6,72.1,22.5,62.9,34.2C53.6,45.8,37.1,51.1,19.7,59.9C2.4,68.7,-15.7,80.9,-24.3,74.4C-32.9,68,-32,43,-36.8,25.6C-41.7,8.2,-52.5,-1.5,-50.6,-8.3C-48.7,-15.2,-34.1,-19.3,-23.6,-33.2C-13.1,-47,-6.5,-70.7,0,-70.7C6.5,-70.7,13,-46.9,25.6,-33.4Z;
                                                    
                                                    M36.1,-40.2C51.4,-30.3,71.5,-23.2,71.4,-14C71.3,-4.8,51.1,6.5,37.5,13.8C23.9,21.1,17,24.4,6.9,35C-3.2,45.7,-16.5,63.7,-23.2,62C-30,60.3,-30.2,38.9,-33.3,23.9C-36.4,8.9,-42.4,0.2,-46.9,-14.2C-51.4,-28.5,-54.5,-48.6,-46.4,-59.7C-38.4,-70.9,-19.2,-73.2,-4.4,-68C10.4,-62.8,20.9,-50.1,36.1,-40.2Z;
                            
                                                    M35.5,-41.2C48.2,-31.7,62.1,-22.5,70.7,-7.5C79.3,7.6,82.5,28.5,73.4,40.6C64.3,52.6,42.9,55.7,26.4,53.4C10,51,-1.4,43.2,-11.9,37.3C-22.3,31.5,-31.7,27.6,-36.2,20.6C-40.7,13.5,-40.2,3.2,-38.7,-7.1C-37.3,-17.5,-34.7,-27.9,-28.1,-38.5C-21.5,-49,-10.7,-59.7,0.3,-60.1C11.4,-60.5,22.8,-50.7,35.5,-41.2Z;
                                                    
                                                    M34.2,-37.4C48.6,-28.8,67.2,-22,69.5,-11.9C71.8,-1.7,57.7,11.7,46.2,22.1C34.8,32.5,26,40,15.8,44C5.5,47.9,-6.2,48.5,-17.9,45.7C-29.6,42.9,-41.3,36.7,-54.5,25.7C-67.8,14.7,-82.6,-1.3,-79.2,-12.8C-75.8,-24.4,-54.2,-31.6,-37.9,-39.8C-21.7,-48.1,-10.8,-57.4,-0.4,-56.9C10,-56.3,19.9,-46,34.2,-37.4Z;
                            
                                                    M46.8,-53.3C55.6,-48.4,54.1,-28.9,52.8,-12.8C51.5,3.3,50.4,15.8,43.8,23.4C37.2,31,25.2,33.7,11.7,43.5C-1.7,53.2,-16.7,70.1,-28.8,69.8C-40.8,69.4,-49.9,51.7,-56.8,35.1C-63.7,18.4,-68.4,2.8,-67.8,-13.9C-67.2,-30.5,-61.2,-48.2,-49,-52.4C-36.8,-56.7,-18.4,-47.5,0.3,-47.9C19,-48.3,38,-58.1,46.8,-53.3Z;
                                                    ">
            </animate>
        </path>
     </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you did was add one too many `;` to the `values` attribute. If you remove the last one it should work.

```html
<div class="contenuto-svg">
  <svg viewBox="-85 -85 170 170" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <defs>
            <filter id="blur">
               <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="4.8" />
            </filter>
            <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="100%">
                <stop offset="10%" stop-color="#9DB6F2" />
                <stop offset="70%" stop-color="#FF5321" />
                <stop offset="20%" stop-color="#FF2E00" />
            </linearGradient>
        </defs>
        <path fill="url(#gradient)" style="opacity: 1;" filter="url(#blur)">
            <animate attributeName="d" dur="20000ms" repeatCount="indefinite"
                         values="M46.8,-53.3C55.6,-48.4,54.1,-28.9,52.8,-12.8C51.5,3.3,50.4,15.8,43.8,23.4C37.2,31,25.2,33.7,11.7,43.5C-1.7,53.2,-16.7,70.1,-28.8,69.8C-40.8,69.4,-49.9,51.7,-56.8,35.1C-63.7,18.4,-68.4,2.8,-67.8,-13.9C-67.2,-30.5,-61.2,-48.2,-49,-52.4C-36.8,-56.7,-18.4,-47.5,0.3,-47.9C19,-48.3,38,-58.1,46.8,-53.3Z;
 M38.9,-46.9C53,-34.5,69,-24.7,67.4,-14.7C65.8,-4.7,46.7,5.6,36.9,20C27,34.3,26.5,52.7,19.6,56.2C12.8,59.7,-0.3,48.3,-11.3,40.3C-22.3,32.3,-31.1,27.7,-34.4,20.5C-37.7,13.4,-35.5,3.8,-38.3,-11.3C-41.1,-26.5,-48.9,-47,-43.4,-61C-37.8,-75,-18.9,-82.3,-3.3,-78.4C12.4,-74.5,24.7,-59.3,38.9,-46.9Z;
                            
                                                    M25.6,-33.4C38.3,-19.9,57.2,-16.7,65.6,-6.1C74.1,4.6,72.1,22.5,62.9,34.2C53.6,45.8,37.1,51.1,19.7,59.9C2.4,68.7,-15.7,80.9,-24.3,74.4C-32.9,68,-32,43,-36.8,25.6C-41.7,8.2,-52.5,-1.5,-50.6,-8.3C-48.7,-15.2,-34.1,-19.3,-23.6,-33.2C-13.1,-47,-6.5,-70.7,0,-70.7C6.5,-70.7,13,-46.9,25.6,-33.4Z;
                                                    
                                                    M36.1,-40.2C51.4,-30.3,71.5,-23.2,71.4,-14C71.3,-4.8,51.1,6.5,37.5,13.8C23.9,21.1,17,24.4,6.9,35C-3.2,45.7,-16.5,63.7,-23.2,62C-30,60.3,-30.2,38.9,-33.3,23.9C-36.4,8.9,-42.4,0.2,-46.9,-14.2C-51.4,-28.5,-54.5,-48.6,-46.4,-59.7C-38.4,-70.9,-19.2,-73.2,-4.4,-68C10.4,-62.8,20.9,-50.1,36.1,-40.2Z;
                            
                                                    M35.5,-41.2C48.2,-31.7,62.1,-22.5,70.7,-7.5C79.3,7.6,82.5,28.5,73.4,40.6C64.3,52.6,42.9,55.7,26.4,53.4C10,51,-1.4,43.2,-11.9,37.3C-22.3,31.5,-31.7,27.6,-36.2,20.6C-40.7,13.5,-40.2,3.2,-38.7,-7.1C-37.3,-17.5,-34.7,-27.9,-28.1,-38.5C-21.5,-49,-10.7,-59.7,0.3,-60.1C11.4,-60.5,22.8,-50.7,35.5,-41.2Z;
                                                    
                                                    M34.2,-37.4C48.6,-28.8,67.2,-22,69.5,-11.9C71.8,-1.7,57.7,11.7,46.2,22.1C34.8,32.5,26,40,15.8,44C5.5,47.9,-6.2,48.5,-17.9,45.7C-29.6,42.9,-41.3,36.7,-54.5,25.7C-67.8,14.7,-82.6,-1.3,-79.2,-12.8C-75.8,-24.4,-54.2,-31.6,-37.9,-39.8C-21.7,-48.1,-10.8,-57.4,-0.4,-56.9C10,-56.3,19.9,-46,34.2,-37.4Z;
                            
                                                    M46.8,-53.3C55.6,-48.4,54.1,-28.9,52.8,-12.8C51.5,3.3,50.4,15.8,43.8,23.4C37.2,31,25.2,33.7,11.7,43.5C-1.7,53.2,-16.7,70.1,-28.8,69.8C-40.8,69.4,-49.9,51.7,-56.8,35.1C-63.7,18.4,-68.4,2.8,-67.8,-13.9C-67.2,-30.5,-61.2,-48.2,-49,-52.4C-36.8,-56.7,-18.4,-47.5,0.3,-47.9C19,-48.3,38,-58.1,46.8,-53.3Z">
            </animate>
        </path>
     </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: A thousand thanks!! it worked